# Why not precompiled js and css files

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, deployment, compilation

When deploy server not compiled stylesheets and javascripts. Until the last moment Asset compiled. Ruby 2.1.2p95, Nginx, Unicorn.
My Assets path:
app

```
--->assets
----->javascripts
------->admin
------->design
----->stylesheets
------->admin
------->design
----------->new_design
----------->new_design_work_page
```

My production.rb

```
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_assets = false
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.version = '1.0'
  config.log_level = :info
  config.assets.precompile += %w( design/*, admin/*, design/new_design/*.css.scss,
    design/new_design_work_page/*.css.scss)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
```

Application.rb:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
require 'rails/all'
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
module Izotorg
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/ckeditor)
    config.assets.precompile += %w( design/*, admin/*, design/new_design/*.css.scss,
    design/new_design_work_page/*.css.scss)
    config.time_zone = 'Moscow'
    config.encoding = "utf-8"
    config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    config.i18n.default_locale = :ru
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you run `rake assets:precompiled RAILS_ENV=production` ?

Comment: when the project started deploe command rake assets:precompiled RAILS_ENV=production.while those files that have been added in the new styles are not compiled.

Comment: Okay, so you need separate files for the styles which are not compiled currently?

Comment: Yes, I am made ​​changes in two files. like this assets / stylesheets / new_design / new_template_styles.css.scss it connects through assets / stylesheets / new_design / new_base.css.scss in new_desig

Comment: instead of each folder base.css.scss

Comment: I think you're not including your dirs properly - let me write an ansewr for you

Answer (score 0):

**Directories**

Okay, I think you might want to look at Rails [globbing](http://apidock.com/ruby/Dir/glob/class), as if you have a "deep" folder, it likely won't append the files to your asset pipeline without having had the folder pattern defined correctly

You can either define the globbing pattern in the asset [`manifest`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives) file, or in the `config.assets.precompile` option:

--

**Manifest**

If you didn't mind putting all the new files into a central `application.css` file like this:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.css
/*
  *= require_tree /design
*/
```

This will take the contents of that file, when you precompile, and put them into the main `application.css` file. This obviously increases the size of the `application.css` file - making it much more beneficial to know how to include individual folders / files outside the manifest system

--

**Pipeline**

If you wanted to keep several different files, you'll want to set the `config.assets.precompile` option in the Rails asset pipeline:

```
#config/environments/production.rb
config.assets.precompile += ["design/*"]
```

Comment: Thanks but I have two basic css one for admin another for other purposes

Comment: error message gets out: Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'design'

Comment: Hmm okay - maybe we could try `/design/*` ?

Comment: Sprockets::ArgumentError: require_tree argument must be a directory